# Error in catalina.logs 'Error flushing stream UDP:localhost:514'

Tags: tomcat, logging, syslog, rsyslog, catalina.out

I am getting following error in catalina.logs

> 2019-09-06 10:11:07,219 localhost-startStop-1 ERROR Unable to write to
>   stream UDP:localhost:514 for appender SYSLOGappender:
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error
>   flushing stream UDP:localhost:514 2019-09-06 10:11:07,224
>   localhost-startStop-1 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender
>   SYSLOGappender
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error
>   flushing stream UDP:localhost:514

What does this error means? What should I debug?

Comment: Can you show the string `Caused by:...`? It should be below.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Message too long
        at java.base/java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:695)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramOutputStream.flush(DatagramOutputStream.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flushDestination(OutputStreamManager.java:270)
        ... 34 more

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about your system of logging (logs) in `Tomcat`.
But this error tells that there is problem with transmission too long message. Possible, it Is might be related with using UDP-protocol in Syslog appender, because in this way messages can have only a size of 65,507 bytes. It's just suggestion is to try set protocol `TCP` instead `UDP` for logging.

Comment: I have this problem too (using `FileAppender`).